# How to define unit principal normal vector $N(t)=\frac{f '(t)\times(f ''(t)\times f '(t))}{||f'(t)||*||f ''(t)\times f '(t)||}$

Tags: calculus, vectors, vector-analysis, self-learning, cross-product

Let f(t) be a smooth curve such that $f'(t)\not=0$ for all t. Then we can define *unit* tangent vector **T** by $T(t)=\frac{f'(t)}{||f'(t)||}$. So $$T'(t)=\frac{f'(t)\times(f''(t)\times f'(t))}{||f'(t)||^3}$$

Now, assume that **f '(t)** and **f ''(t)** are not parallel. Then $T'(t)\not=0$, so we can define *unit* principal normal vector **N** by $$N(t)=\frac{T '(t)}{||T '(t)||}$$.

Now, how to show that $$N(t)=\frac{f'(t)\times(f''(t)\times f'(t))}{||f'(t)||*||f''(t)||\times ||f'(t)||}$$

My attempt:
$$N(t)=\frac{f'(t)\times(f''(t)\times f'(t))}{||f'(t)||^3*||T'(t)||}$$

I don't understand how to compute $$||T'(t)||=\frac{||f'(t)\times (f''(t)\times f'(t))||}{||\left(||f'(t)||^3\right)||}$$

If any member knows the correct answer to this question, may reply with correct answer.

Comment: Question is solved.